# Why was this person not affected (Arrow)

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

Some spoilers may appear.

How come in green arrow people who are injected with the mirakuru die. But Slade and Roy survived. Why did these people not die and how?

Comment: Feel free to fix any writting mistakes:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Arrow Wiki](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Mirakuru):

> the use of the serum is dangerous, as it can easily prove fatal to its subjects if not correctly administered.

So it would seem that Oliver somehow correctly administered it to Slade.

Sebastian Blood obtained the serum from Slade's blood and injected Roy, who then bled from his eyes and appeared to die, but he was revived by Oliver.

Comment: Oh ok. Props to Oliver. But what about Roy. How did he not die?

Comment: Looks like the key for both of them was to be near Oliver . . .

Comment: Ahhah. Prbly. Thanks for the time put in to the answer. Hope your having a great Friday!

Comment: Ohh you edited your answer. Thanks for that. @BrentZundel